# How prepare statement with bindvalue and %?

Tags: sql, pdo, bindvalue

Yes I have a issue when i try to use bindvalues on the variables that looked like this before:

```
users.firstname LIKE '$firstname%'
```

Now it looks like this:

```
users.firstname LIKE ':firstname%'
```

But it doesn't work, also tried this:

```
users.firstname LIKE :firstname%
```

And got some syntax error..

What is the correct solution for this? I also thought adding the % in the bindValue(:firstname, $firstname%) but i need to use the :firstname in other places too that should not have the %..

Help thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, add the `%` to the bound value:

```
users.firstname LIKE :firstname
```

And then

```
$stmt->bindValue(':firstname', $firstname . '%');
```

But, since you're saying you need to use `:firstname` in other places, just name this instance something different:

```
users.firstname LIKE :firstnamewild
```

And then

```
$stmt->bindValue(':firstnamewild', $firstname . '%');
```