# Correct syntax for PDO LIKE statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a mysql query using PDO, where i would like to use the LIKE statement to search my database for values.

I am currently using the query

```
$selectdp = $connection->prepare(
    "SELECT `FilePath`,`ItemPicID`,`Extension`
    FROM `ItemPics`
    WHERE `BusinessID`=:bizid
    AND `ItemID`=:itemid
    AND `FilePath` LIKE :search ");
```

with

```
$selectdp->bindValue(":search",'%DP');
```

but i am getting the error

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%DP' ....

Things i've tried in the query

- LIKE=:search
- LIKE CONCAT('%'.:search)

I've taken a look at

[implement LIKE query in PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117134/implement-like-query-in-pdo) and [How prepare statement with bindvalue and %?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783750/pdo-prepared-statement-with-bindvalue-and) but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: You sure you've got a space between `LIKE` and `:search`?

Comment: yes i do have a space between LIKE and :search

Comment: Please note that it's unnecessary and distracting to quote your column and table names.

Comment: possible duplicate of [implement LIKE query in PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117134/implement-like-query-in-pdo)

Comment: @davidstrachan not even close

Answer (score 1):

I was taught to concatenate for LIKE expressions within the SQL, and set a parameter within the concatenation. For example:

```
$selectdp = $connection->prepare(
    "SELECT `FilePath`,`ItemPicID`,`Extension`
    FROM `ItemPics`
    WHERE `BusinessID`=:bizid
    AND `ItemID`=:itemid
    AND `FilePath` LIKE concat('%', :search)
```

Take a look at [Kzqai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583336/how-do-i-create-a-pdo-parameterized-query-with-a-like-statement/7357296#7357296) here, who seems to understand it much more than I do.

From his explanation, a primary difficult with this is preventing the wildcard character from acting as a literal.